# Какой параметр jvmArgs нужно добавить в build.gradle для считывания конкретного файла *.properties при запуске тестов через Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, selenide

В проекте автотестов на Java + selenide есть разные файлы *.properties, в которых указаны url тестовой среды и логопас для логина. Тесты запускаю через Jenkins. В Jenkins создал параметр TARGET_ENV, где указываю имя тестовой среды. В проекте есть класс PropertyLoader, где указана дефолтная тестовая среда. В build.gradle в разделе test указаны различные параметры jvmArgs для запуска тестов. Как я понимаю, сюда же нужно добавить какой-то параметр, который позволит получать на вход имя тестовой среды, которое будет влиять на то, какой из файлов *.properties прочитать (например, dev.properties)
Сейчас читается файл, который задан по умолчанию в классе PropertyLoader

```
package util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertyLoader {

private final Properties PROPERTIES = loadProperties();

private Properties loadProperties() {
    Properties property = new Properties();
    String env = System.getProperty("env", "int");
    try {
        property.load(new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/" + env + ".properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return property;
}

public String getProperty(String key) {
    return PROPERTIES.getProperty(key);
}
}
```

Какой параметр jvmArgs нужно добавить в build.gradle? Пробовал по всякому гуглить, успехов нет